# Scala project Unit Test Sucess in SonarQube

Tags: scala, unit-testing, sbt, sonarqube

is it possible to get sonarqube to show the unit test success (ie. how many unit tests there were, % that passed etc) for a scala project with SBT? I currently have the plugins "sbt-scoverage", "sbt-scapegoat" and "sbt-sonarrunner-plugin" in relation to this. I also have java tests in this project and I've gotten them to show the Unit Test Success, but I haven't had any success getting the Unit Test Success for my scala tests to show.

Is there some other plugin I can get that will allow me to do this? I've searched everywhere in the documentation for these plugins but I haven't found anything that implies it is possible.

Here are the settings I currently have set for the scala section, and the actual paths are all correct (obviously these are fake paths).

```
"sonar.projectName" -> "projectName",
"sonar.scoverage.reportPath" -> "path/to/scoverage.xml",
"sonar.junit.reportsPath" -> "path/to/test-reports",
"sonar.sources" -> "project/src/main/scala",
"sonar.tests" -> "project/src/test/scala"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"sonar.junit.reportsPath" is the setting that is needed to show the unit test success. When I looked at the output of the logs however I discovered that it was expecting files that looked like "TEST-*.xml". Adding "TEST-" to the beginning of each xml file after the coverage is run allowed the unit test success results to show up on sonarqube.